# Exercise on iid sequence of uniformly distributed random variables (and LLN).

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve following problem:

Let $X_{1}, Y_{1}, X_{2}, Y_{2},\ldots$ - iid, from uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, $f\colon[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be measurable and $Z_{j} = \mathbb{1}_{\{f(X_{j}) > Y_{j}\}}$ for j = 1,2,...

Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}{\sum}_{j = 1}^{n}Z_{j} = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)xdx$

I know that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)xdx$ is an expected value of random variable $f(X_{1})$. By SLLN if $Z_{j}$ is integrable, sums $\frac{1}{n}{\sum}_{j = 1}^{n}Z_{j}$ converge almost surely to the expected value of $Z_{j}$, so I need to calculate it.

$\mathbb{E}Z_{j} = \mathbb{P}(f(X_{1}) > Y_{1})$ by definition of expected value. Now I need tips on what to do next.

EDIT: Thank you!

Comment: Uhm...err... If *this* $f$ is the pdf of the i.i.d. uniform distributions over $[0;1]$ , then $f(X_1)=1$ and $\Bbb P(1>Y_1) = 1 \;\mathrm{ a.s.}$ .  I suspect that this may be some *other* measurable function confusingly named $f$ rather than $g$ or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there, except for confusion as to the nature of $f$.

Note that $f$ is **not** the probability density function of the uniform distributions.   It is some *other* measurable function.

The pdf of the iid uniform distributions is: $1$ over the support $[0;1]$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Then it is simply that:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \tfrac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^\infty Z_k
 & = \Bbb E(Z_\ast)
\\[-1ex] & = \Bbb E(\mathbf 1_{\{Y_\ast< f(X_\ast)\}})
\\[1ex] & = \Bbb P\big(\{Y_\ast< f(X_\ast)\}\big)
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1 \int_0^{f(x)} 1\;\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^1 f(x)\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

That is all.